# Exception in mail queue send function

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

In my app I am trying to send an email using `Mail::queue()`.

I get an exception saying that serialization of closure failed.

> ErrorException in SerializableClosure.php line 93: Serialization of
>   closure failed: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

I have a this as the send function:

```
public function send()
{
    $view = view('emails.welcome');
    $data = [
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ];

    return $this->mailer->queue($view, $data, function($message){
        $message->to($this->to)->subject($this->subject);
    });
}
```

I've only recently begun using Laravel so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The issue it that you're trying to use `$this` inside Closure.

Please provide parameters $to and $subject using `use` keyword like in this example:

```
return $this->mailer->queue($view, $data, function($message) use ($to, $subject) {
    $message->to($to)->subject($subject);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is using **$this** inside of the closure.

`$this->to` and `$this->subject` are references to fields on the Class and not in the Closure so to fix the code make them local variables and pass them to closure like as below:

```
public function send()
{
    $to = $this->getTo();
    $subject = $this->getSubject();

    return $this->mailer->queue( $this->getView(), $this->getData(), $this->getData(), 
    function($message) use($to, $subject) {
        $message->to($to)->subject($subject);
    });
}
```